# Does 'require' in Scala introduce performance penalty?

Tags: performance, scala

I really like using `require` checks while writing new classes in Scala. But I am worried about performance cost they may add.

So main question - is there a cost for using `require`?
Right now I assume that every time instance of a class is created, condition in `require` is checked, and that is the only cost. But I am not sure, maybe there are some other penalties or contrary maybe it's optimized in some tricky way.

I realize that in most cases performance penalty, even if it exists will be negligible compared to benefits. But what about following example:

I am generating many (1 million) instances of some class, consisting of two fields and three functions, during Monte-Carlo simulation and performing some simple manipulations with those instances. Will you advise using `require` for such scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, `require` is implemented as an assertion whetever they appear. You are obviously talking about `require` in the constructor body. It's just the test, really, and there's even a parameter to `scalac` that will omit these instructions (that is, no code will be generated for them).

You can check these things yourself using `javap`.

Let this be an initial answer until someone comes with something more precise.

Comment: I can't say for certain but based on this other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002835/what-is-the-meaning-of-an-assumption-in-scala-compared-to-an-assertion) it seems only `assert` and `assume` are disabled. Also both [this](http://xuwei-k.github.io/scala-library-sxr/scala-library-2.10.0/scala/Predef.scala.html) and [this](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/annotation/elidable.html) seems to backup the fact that `require` can't be toggled.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me to realize that 'require' is just a usual function which may be used anywhere. Unfortunately in many Scala tutorials and books 'require' is introduced only as a part of constructor without any additional explanation, which lead me to confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `require` keyword allows you to basically do sanity checks (e.g. null pointer). I believe the "message" part (`require(foo != null, "message")`) part is not processed until it fails which in this case occurs when foo does equal to `null`. It throws `IllegalArgumentException` and is fairly similar to `assert` and `assume`.

I would assume you would incur minimal performance cost for using it since it can be easily described as `if (!stmt) throw IllegalArgumentException`. Obviously, it has some cost but probably not the first thing you'll want to improve upon.

See this [question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002835/what-is-the-meaning-of-an-assumption-in-scala-compared-to-an-assertion).

EDIT: I should add that the null pointer check is fairly bad since you have things like `Try(..)` and `Some(..)`.

Comment: No I didn't have null checks in mind when I was asking the question. I try to avoid using null at all cost anywhere in the code. I meant use-cases where you need to specify some relations between fields, or add constraints to fields. For example in poker your hand may consist of 2 (preflop), 5 (flop), 6(turn) or 7(river) cards - this is a good candidate for 'require'. Similarly if naive Card class is implemented using value and suit fields, I will 'require' that value is from 1 to 13. Still I get what you are talking about, thanks for reply.

Comment: Oh, I referring to my example of the null check in the `require`